# Print value of 2nd pattern if 1st pattern matches username

Tags: linux, awk, wildcards

I have been trying to write a script with `awk` to print the name of a users rolegroup(s), if the username matches an input variable.

The input file is similar to the following

```
sssss
xxxname
trevor
xxxage
21
xxxrolegroups
activedir
sssss
xxxname
gus
xxxage30
xxxrolegroups
sssss
```

As you can see, the file is separated by `sssss`. I know that the name I am looking for is `trevor` and I want the script to print the value `activedir`. 
The fields aren't always in the same order (there are multiple fields, this just being an example).

I tried the following...

```
USERNAME=`cat trevor.txt`
awk 'BEGIN {RS="sssss"; FS="\n";} if username=$USERNAME then {awk '/xxrolegroups/ {getline; print }}'
```

Please excuse the pseudo-code, just trying to convey what I'm trying to do :-)

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to U&L. Please add an example of the desired output to your question.

Comment: Also, please differentiate whether your input file is the `trevor.txt` from your example, and if not, what `trevor.txt` contains. (my assumption is it simply contains `trevor`, if I understand your question)

Comment: Should the script print `activedir` when it's found `trevor`, or only if it finds this keyword in `trevor`'s block? Should it print anything if it cannot find `activedir` in the block containing `trevor`?

Comment: I'd use a more capable language for such a task, like Python or Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script like this. I've split it up to help with readability, but you can literally concatenate all the lines if you prefer:

```
awk -v key=trevor '
    BEGIN { RS="^sssss$"; RE="\n" key "\n" }
    $0 ~ RE && /activedir/ { print "activedir" }
' datafile.txt
```

It sets the record separator to a line consisting of `sssss` and creates a Regular Expression that matches the key `trevor` to a full line within that record. Then, if it can match the RE and it finds `activedir` it prints the required text.